# How to show an video while converting from one format to another format using ffmpeg in php.?

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

Presently i am writing a one application in php.
which can be able to convert one format to another format using ffmpeg.

Example: AVI to MP4

Here my client wants

> "while converting he want's to see the ongoing converting video file
>   like shown in standard video converting softwares"

Is it possilble in PHP or is there any options available in ffmpeg

Comment: maybe create some thumbnails of the video to be processed, then run ffmpeg and parse its progress so you know about which thumbnail to display...

Comment: yes that sounds like a good approach

Comment: @rogerdpack how do we know about which thumbnail to display while converting..?
here my file conversions are done while file uploading to server..
so how can i create thumbnails to those videos.?

Comment: you generate thumbnails "for every 2 minutes" of the video, then parse the ffmpeg output [or use its "progress" output option might help] then somehow you want to display that back to the user, that part I don't know :)